# Groupby aggregation and create dictionary based on condition in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data frame as shown below. which is the table which explains the modules watched by users on each courses.

```
user_id     course_id       module_id
1           1               1
1           1               2
1           1               3
1           1               4
1           1               5
1           1               6
1           2               5
1           2               8
2           1               8
2           2               5
2           3               6
3           1               2
3           1               3
3           1               9
3           3               10
```

From the above data, I would like prepare below table.

Expected Output:

```
user_id     courses   Num_ofcourses     Total                         Total_Modules
1           [1,2]     2                 {1:[1,2,3,4,5,6], 2:[5,8]}    8
2           [1,2,3]   3                 {1:[8], 2:[5], 3:[6]}         3 
3           [1,3]     2                 {1:[2,3,9], 3:[10]}           4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is first create nested dictionaries for `Total` column, then aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.unique.html), [`SeriesGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and last add new column by [`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) and [`Index.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.map.html):

```
s = df.groupby(['user_id','course_id'])['module_id'].apply(list)
d = {x: s.xs(x).to_dict() for x in s.index.levels[0]}

df1 = df.groupby('user_id').agg(courses=('course_id','unique'),
                               Num_ofcourses=('course_id','nunique'),
                               Total_Modules=('module_id','size'))

df1.insert(2, 'Total', df1.index.map(d))
df1 = df1.reset_index()
print (df1)
   user_id    courses  Num_ofcourses                               Total  \
0        1     [1, 2]              2  {1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2: [5, 8]}   
1        2  [1, 2, 3]              3            {1: [8], 2: [5], 3: [6]}   
2        3     [1, 3]              2             {1: [2, 3, 9], 3: [10]}   

   Total_Modules  
0              8  
1              3  
2              4
```

Comment: I am facing below errors
aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

Comment: @ALI - hmmm, if remove `courses=('course_id','unique'),` it working?

Comment: @ALI - One idea, can youi test if working with sample data? `df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'course_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3], 'module_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 8, 8, 5, 6, 2, 3, 9, 10]})`

Comment: @ALI - If remove `courses=('course_id','unique'),
                               Num_ofcourses=('course_id','nunique'),` like `df1 = df.groupby('user_id').agg(Total_Modules=('module_id','size'))` working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208796/discussion-between-ali-and-jezrael).